# Relacionamento de duas tabelas MYSQLI

Tags: sql

Estou tentando relacionar duas tabelas para que o resultado fique assim;

Endereço para teste da consulta http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d9acad/1

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei usar o comando abaixo;

```
SELECT 
    item_inventarios.sku,
    item_inventarios.cod_setor,
    inventario_ambientes.setor_ini,
    inventario_ambientes.setor_fim,
    inventario_ambientes.desc_ambiente
FROM 
    item_inventarios,inventario_ambientes
WHERE 
    item_inventarios.`id_inventario`='46' 
and inventario_ambientes.id_inventario = item_inventarios.id_inventario
```

**O resultado esta gerando assim;**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Tabela inventario_ambientes**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
**Tabela item_inventarios**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Algumas orientações sobre a sua pergunta: 1) Explique melhor o resultado final esperado. O que é o relacionamento? Qual é a relação entre os dados apontados? 2) Adicione na sua pergunta o que você já tentou fazer, mesmo que não tenha dado certo. Assim temos um ponto do qual partir. 3) Ao invés de inserir imagens, insira os dados. Facilita para copiarmos e ajudarmos com uma resposta.

Comment: Obrigado! ajustei a pegunta.

Comment: Ainda faltou colocar o que tem como imagem como texto para que possamos reproduzir seu código.

Comment: Aqui. pode testar meu banco de dados;

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d9acad/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me corrija se eu tiver entendido errado a pergunta, mas creio que você precisa disso:

```sql
SELECT 
    ii.sku,
    ii.cod_setor,
    ia.setor_ini,
    ia.setor_fim,
    ia.desc_ambiente,
    ii.cod_coletor
FROM 
    item_inventarios ii
inner join inventario_ambientes ia on ii.id_inventario = ia.id_inventario
    and ii.cod_setor between setor_ini and setor_fim
WHERE 
    ii.id_inventario = '46' 
order by 1
```

Comment: Editei a pegunta para ficar mais compreensível.

Comment: Não entendi a lógica do resultado que vc deseja. O que precisa exatamente?

Comment: Preciso incluir a coluna `desc_ambiente` da `tabela inventario_ambientes` contrarrespondente a coluna   `cod_setor` da tabela `item_inventarios`, porem a relação entre `cod_setor` com a tabela `desc_ambiente` está entre `setor_ini` e `setor_fim`

Exemplo

Tabela **inventario_ambientes** Tenho o cod_setor= 1 e 2 e acharia os mesmos valores na coluna setor_ini e setor_fim da tabela inventario_ambientes

Comment: Editei a query, confira se está ok

Comment: Perfeito ! funcionou